# XAMPP, PhpStorm: waiting for incoming connection with ide key

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am literally freaking out because of this. 
I tried every possible setting, but I can't get this to work.

I tried with 4 different Firefox extensions and with Google Chrome. Xdebug won't work, my PhpStorm Debugger window keeps saying:

> waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'xxxxx'

(xxxxx is a random number, it changes with every debug, the last was 10131)

My php.ini located in C:\xampp\php\php.ini

```
[Xdebug]

zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey='phpstorm'
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value=1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value=1
xdebug.remote_log=c:/xampp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log
```

I tried changing the port number from 9000 to 9001 for example, no chance.

No xdebug log file is created at all.

PhpStorm Settings:

[image: PhpStorm/Settings/Php/Debug]

[image: PhpStorm/Run/Edit Configuration/Php Web Application]

I tried different configurations, too, but no chance. Please help me.

Comment: Please post your `phpinfo()` output as captured via browser. In particular: first table with general info + xdebug section.

Comment: It didn't allow me to post more than 2 links, now I posted them, see below.

Comment: Please re-post them as a comment and not as separate answer.

Comment: In any case -- we need to see xdebug log to see what is going on. So ... 1) Try using `c:\` kind of path instead of `C:/` 2) use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` -- does it make any difference? 3) You can also try placing `xdebug_break()` in your code -- any difference?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5fO79.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0BoK.png

I used c:xampp/.. still no log. 2) did it, no difference. 3) put it, no difference.

Comment: I mean to use \ as path separator instead of / . For me -- you must be doing something wrong here... P.S. I can do a TeamViewer session if you wish (in next half an hour or so only)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yeah, I changed the seperator, too. Didnt work. Yeah, TeamViewer would be great, how to contact you? I prepare everything then.